# Android Ignition RemoteImageView not functioning properly

Tags: android, android-imageview, droid-fu

I have a very basic app with two ignition-remoteimageviews (RIV) in them. The app seems to function properly except for the fact that instead of the image, I get two grey triangles with exclamation points in them where the image should be. My test image URL is "http://developer.android.com/images/home/android-design.png" As of this posting the image loads in my browser, therefore I believe the problem to be elsewhere. I have only placed the two riv's in the layout. I have yet to code the corresponding Java. Is the failure due to the fact that I haven't added the needed java yet, or is there something else amiss? I made a test app earlier using ignition and I don't recall having to add java to get the most basic functionality. I can post the code if need be, but I am sure this will boil down to me being a clot and forgetting something easy.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to explain what **Ignition** and `RemoteImageView` are. Don't expect people to know what you're talking about and having to search for what they are should be something you do for us. Also, post only the relevant code to your problem. Finally, yes, you will need to use Java to download an image.

Comment: All I was asking was if RemoteImageView was java-dependent. Thank you for the answer. 

I don't understand the need to explain every object. If I ask a question about a TableLayout, am I going to have to explain what a TableLayout is every time? All of my previous questions were answered by people familiar with ignition. I don't ask questions in the hopes of making someone go around and look up information. The question was relatively straight forward and I tried to phrase it in a way to require the least effort on the part of anyone who chose to answer.

Comment: Ignition and RemoteView are part of the Android API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have waited about an hour and my question would not have cost me two rep. For some reason, when I granted the permission, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, it did not take. Once I re-established this permission, both RIV's worked fine *without* java.

Ignition is an external library project or seperate jar with a few fancy classes. In this case RemoteImageView allows for displaying remote images. It will also automatically cache them...

My apologies for the question as it did come down to something dumb I forgot... But that was the crux of the question in the first place.